# Coordinate system Italy Sicily

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, epsg, dxf, italy

I've received a .dxf file of a small area in Sicily. Now I have a problem with the coordinate system. It's not the usual European UTM or similar. I absolutely cannot find what coordinate system it is.

The extent is

-4011.0709999999999127,-4410.8940000000002328

-790.0000000000000000,-2388.5529999999998836

I have been using QGIS (without Python) for a long time and I know my way around. Here I have not found a way to get the EPSG from the metadata. or is there a way?

I googled a lot but couldn't find the system.

[image: example for one point in the area]

Comment: Your screenshot of coordinates do not match your written coordinates?

Comment: Can you verify whether the real-world-extent of the area is 400 x 1600 m?

Comment: have you tried reaching out to whoever provided you the .dxf file, or checked your source for any metadata?

Comment: The small numbers suggest a local grid as the extent is only 4 km west and 800 m south of the grid origin.

Comment: I think so too. Do you know where i can find more informations about local grids specially italian ones?